# how to get data from multiple tables on sql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a table result based on PHP & mySQL, I encountered a problem where I would be pulling multiple data in tables with multiple condition, I also got error (mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result). Here are some of the codes:

```
<?php
    include('mysql.php');
    mysqli_select_db($con,"iiumsystem");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT stu_id, org_name, suv_id, stu_mark
            FROM (SELECT * FROM student
            INNER JOIN organization
            ON org_name.stu_id = stu_id
            WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR organization.stu_id ='?')) AS matches
            INNER JOIN supervisor
            ON suv_id.stu_id = stu_id
            WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR supervisor.stu_id ='?')) AS matches
            INNER JOIN mark
            ON stu_mark.stu_id = stu_id
            WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR mark.stu_id ='?')) AS matches";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


          {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='result'>".$row['stu_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td class='result'>".$row['suv_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td class='result'>".$row['org_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td class='result'>".$row['stu_mark']."</td>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: You should add some error reporting, the SQL is invalid (WHERE should come after JOINs), the placeholders should not be in quotes and you haven't bound any params to the placeholders in the query.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain/teach me about JOIN command because this is my first time using it so i bit lost.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php | http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php | http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it. Can you show me example?

Answer (score 0):

This clearly says you have some error in your sql query.

Try to print $sql query with parameters value in and run it into any mysql client i.e. phpmyadmin. It will show you correct query error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stu_id, org_name, suv_id, stu_mark FROM 
(SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN organization ON org_name.stu_id = stu_id WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR organization.stu_id ='?')) 
AS matches 
INNER JOIN supervisor ON suv_id.stu_id = stu_id
WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR supervisor.stu_id ='?') AS matches
INNER JOIN mark
ON stu_mark.stu_id = stu_id
WHERE (student.stu_id = '?' OR mark.stu_id ='?') AS matches
```

Try this. You had two extra parantheses after the `WHERE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but all of those subqueries aren't going to help you.

```
SELECT student.stu_id, organization.org_name, supervisor.suv_id, mark.stu_mark
FROM student
INNER JOIN organization
    ON organization.stu_id = student.stu_id
INNER JOIN supervisor
    ON supervisor.stu_id = student.stu_id
INNER JOIN mark
    ON mark.stu_id = student.stu_id
```

But I'm confused about your architecture here. From what I can make out of your query, it looks like there's a one-to-many relationship between `student` and each of `supervisor`, `organization`, and `mark`. I would expect the relationship to be:

- `student` has one `supervisor`
- `student` has one `organization`
- `student` has many `mark`

In that case, `student` would have a `org_id` and `suv_id` field, while `mark` would have a `stu_id` field. You would then write the query as:

```
SELECT student.stu_id, organization.org_name, supervisor.suv_id
FROM student
LEFT JOIN organization
    ON organization.org_id = student.org_id
LEFT JOIN supervisor
    ON supervisor.sup_id = student.sup_id
```

And I'm not sure what you want to do with `mark`, since I assume you would have a lot of them. `AVG(mark.stu_mark)` maybe?

Comment: Here my relationship
+ student has one supervisor
+supervisor has many student
+student has one Mark

Comment: Not sure why you have a one-to-one relationship between student and mark, but okay. Anyway, you haven't followed up with any of the additional info that people have requested, but this is clearly invalid: `suv_id.stu_id = stu_id`. Should be `supervisor.stu_id`.

Comment: Thank Mikkel. I will try and get back to you guys later. :)